# Serious Camera Crashes and RuntimeException in Android

Tags: android, exception, crash, camera, nullpointerexception

I have create several camera apps and I just release the apps to Google Play market 3 weeks ago. Until now I have receive a lot of crashes reports, as shown below:

**java.lang.RuntimeException**
in android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters
*REPORTS TOTAL:2*

**java.lang.NullPointerException**
in com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.surfaceCreated
*REPORTS TOTAL: 21*

**java.lang.RuntimeException**
in android.hardware.Camera.native_autoFocus
*REPORTS TOTAL: 2*

**java.lang.RuntimeException**
in android.hardware.Camera.native_setup
*REPORTS TOTAL: 12*

Total download until now is around 5000. 
Seem that all the exception and crashes is related to cameras. Here is the source code and methods of CameraSurfaceView

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context context;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        context = c;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        //once image is ready(captured or load), the surfaceCreated will not trigger camera again when user click on settings
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try
        {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); //may throw exception

            Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
            {
                parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            } 
            else 
            {
                parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            }
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void startCamera()   //resume camera
    {
        if(mCamera == null)
        {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            try
            {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);

                Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
                {
                    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                }
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopCamera() //pause camera
    {
        if(mCamera != null)
        {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void onFlashLight()
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    public void offFlashLight()
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    public void takePicture()
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS))
        {
            mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) 
                {
                    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                }
            }); 
        }
        else
        {
            mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    }

    public void autoFocus()
    {
        if(mCamera != null)
            mCamera.autoFocus(null);
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter(){}
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){}
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            //something happens
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the uses-feature and uses-permission i put in manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

So far I have test this application on several devices (Samsung Galaxy SII, Galaxy Note, Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy Y, HTC Desire HD, Sony Xperia) and I can't find any problems or camera crashes when I run the application on these devices.

But the problem is I keep receive crashes reports and emails from users told me that the application keep crashing on their unknown device. It is really frustrated that there are too many types of android devices in the world and I can't test my apps on every device to find out the root cause of problem, unless some one can figure out any mistake I done in my source codes.

Here is stack trace for "**android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters**"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1068)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.onFlashLight(CameraSurfaceView.java:168)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.AutoDistanceActivity.startCameraFlash(AutoDistanceActivity.java:224)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CustomView.onTouchEvent(CustomView.java:876)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1779)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1130)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1763)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2196)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1880)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is stack trace for "**com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.surfaceCreated**"

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(CameraSurfaceView.java:97)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:1108)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:87)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1621)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is stack trace for "**android.hardware.Camera.native_autoFocus**"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: autoFocus failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_autoFocus(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.autoFocus(Camera.java:832)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.autoFocus(CameraSurfaceView.java:212)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.AutoDistanceActivity.startCameraFocus(AutoDistanceActivity.java:235)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CustomView.onTouchEvent(CustomView.java:880)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5604)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1787)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1787)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1787)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1917)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1376)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1865)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5784)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is stack trace for "**android.hardware.Camera.native_setup**"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:294)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:269)
at com.potatotree.autodistance.CameraSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(CameraSurfaceView.java:72)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:552)
at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6994)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6994)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1896)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1527)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1263)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1864)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any expert can help me or can tell me if I do any mistakes in my codes? 
Really need your help!! Thank you

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: Yes it's challenging that there are so many Android device types, but it's not so difficult to write robust code which does not rely on the success of every operation. For example, the only code lines in `surfaceCreated()` which can still throw exceptions are the first line and those in the `catch` block. The first line relies on `Camera.open()` to succeed. However, the documentation says that it will rreturn `null` if the device has no back-facing camera. So you should deal with that I'd say?

Comment: Thanks to Class Stacker. Do you meant that it is better to place the Camera.open() inside the try-catch block?

Comment: Is `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />` will filter out all the devices that don't have the back camera from downloaded by user in Google Play? Or just filter out the devices that don't have the both front and back camera? I found that some tablet that don't have the back camera still can install my application from Google Play. Is there any mistakes on my `<uses-features>`?